# Accessing UNC Share with different Login Credentials

Tags: network-shares, unc

I have a share "\dhiwin7\alice's folder". The machine dhiwin7 has 2 different users bob & alice with different permissions.
I would like to access the CIFS share as alice and then bob , but Windows doesn't prompt for credentials after the first time it had asked for a username and password.How to delete the cached credentials.

BTW Windows Credential Manager did not have the credentials for the machine \dhiwin7

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows won't let you have concurrent connections (and, as such, different credentials) to a CIFS server. After accessing (but not necessarily mapping) a share (or the list of available shares), the connection remains. If you want to close it, you can use the `net use` command:

```
net use delete \\server\ipc$
```

To list currently established connections can also be queried:

```
net use
```

Comment: +1, but could you share the GUI method if you know of one?

Comment: @Louis I thought it was possible, but I remembered incorrectly. That’s what happens when I write answers before having a coffee, ugh.